# Error in EmailMessage.Forward (EWS) method.

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I'm using EWS to read a mailbox and based on a certain conditions, forward the emails out to a set of users. However, the process fails with this error:
"An internal server error occurred. The operation failed."

and this:

"An unhandled exception of type 'Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceResponseException' occurred in Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.dll"

Here's my sample code:

```
                EmailAddress[] emailids = new EmailAddress[4];
                emailids[0] = new EmailAddress("user1@domain.com");
                emailids[1] = new EmailAddress("user2@domain.com");
                msg.Forward("This message was Auto forwarded", emailids);
```

The msg is an object of type EmailMessage in Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you
Abhi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you've defined an array of 4 EmailAddress but you are only using 2 which would cause issues.

Does this fail on every message you try to forward or just certain messages or are you forwarding as batch and fails after a certain number.

There are Throttling restrictions with Exchange http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj945066(v=exchg.150).aspx that can affect a number of things one of those in the recipient limits eg RecipientRateLimit and ForwardeeLimit.

You might also want to enable tracing http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633676(v=exchg.80).aspx and post the full response you get

Cheers
Glen

Comment: Sorry Glen, I was using 4 email address in my original code, I changed the sample to include only 2 , but forgot to change the array size to 2. It was working fine until a couple of days back. But now it fails for every message.

Comment: What version of Exchange are you using ? has the server been updated recently ? One other thing to check is the EWSLog on the CAS server to see if you can get more information about the failure. (Have you also just tried forwarding to one address ?)

Comment: Glen, I checked the EWS Response and it was saying this: "The license is invalid for this mailbox". I was using a service account to access this mailbox. I tried it with a different account and it worked. 
Thank you for the help.